# redundant null check in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, null

I have following line of code in eclipse kepler.

```
if (this != null) {

}
```

This `!= null` show an error "**Redundant null check: this expression cannot be null**" even if i have changed Redundant null check into warning by going through **Java** > **Compiler** > **Errors/Warnings** >   **Null analysis**.

Comment: Why would you check if an instance currently being executed is null? It is most obviously not. I know your question regards the warning vs error, but I am just curious.

Comment: Uh, `this` can never be `null`... If you have `this` your instance exists

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Kepler shows error marks on warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488813/eclipse-kepler-shows-error-marks-on-warnings)

Answer (score 3):

Considering the following:

- The keyword `this` can only be used **inside an instance method**, i.e. in a method which is executed on an existing object.
- `this` refers to the object on which the method is called
- `this` is **read-only** (cannot explicitly assign null to it for example).
- Calling an instance method on a null object would result in an exception.

Therefore, it is guaranteed that `this` is **never** null.

The compiler warning helps you to identify code which makes no sense or code which is never be executed.

**EDIT**: About error / warning behavior of eclipse kepler, see [eclipse-kepler-shows-error-marks-on-warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488813/eclipse-kepler-shows-error-marks-on-warnings)